# Spark Time Series - Custom Group By 10 Minute Intervals: Improve Performance

Tags: time, apache-spark, pyspark, series

We have time series data (timestamp in us since 1970 and integer data value):

```
# load data and cache it
df_cache = readInData() # read data from several files (paritioned by hour)
df_cache.persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
df_cache.agg({"data": "max"}).collect()

# now data is cached
df_cache.show()
+--------------------+---------+
|                time|     data| 
+--------------------+---------+
|1.448409599861109E15|1551.7468|
|1.448409599871109E15|1551.7463|
|1.448409599881109E15|1551.7468|
```

Now we want to calculate some non-trivial things on top of 10 Minute time windows using an external python library. In order to do so, we need to load the data of each time frame in memory, apply the external function and store the result. Therefore a User Defined Aggregate Function (UDAF) is not possible.

Now the problem is, when we apply the GroupBy to the RDD, it is very slow.

```
df_cache.rdd.groupBy(lambda x: int(x.time / 600e6) ). \ # create 10 minute groups
             map(lambda x: 1). \ # do some calculations, e.g. external library
             collect() # get results
```

This operation takes for 120Mio samples (100Hz data) on two nodes with 6GB Ram around 14 minutes. Spark Details for the groupBy stage:

```
Total Time Across All Tasks: 1.2 h
Locality Level Summary: Process local: 8
Input Size / Records: 1835.0 MB / 12097
Shuffle Write: 1677.6 MB / 379
Shuffle Spill (Memory): 79.4 GB
Shuffle Spill (Disk): 1930.6 MB
```

If I use a simple python script and let it iterate over the input files, it takes way less time to finish.

How can this job be optimized in spark?

Comment: I am not sure how feasible this would be, but you might want to map your data with int(x.time, 600e^) as a third member of your tuple, and then reduceByKey onto this member. I am unsure how much you can gain in performance with this, but it should produce smaller shuffle. Let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: Something of this sort : `df_cache.rdd.map(lambda x: (int(x.time/600e^), x.time, x.data) ).reduceByKey(lambda x: 1).collect()` (missed the editing timespan .. !) Be careful with the collect though, this can lead to OOM exceptions.

Comment: I tried this one before. And it was slower than the direct group by.

`asdf

Comment: I can hardly think of anything faster than a reduceByKey. You might want to look at the distribution of the groups produced by your groupBy for any anomalies, and to check out the details for the reduceByKey job, to pinpoint the exact problematic operation. Did you try rewriting your job with Spark SQL's DataFrame ?

Comment: I tried this one before. And it was "as fast as" the direct group by. Here the data for a small part of the data set.

40 s 
collect: 16s
group by: 24s   input: 132MB shuffle write: 120MB
`df_cache.rdd.groupBy(lambda x: int(x.time / 600e6) ).map(lambda x: 1).collect()`

1min 9s
collect: 45s
group by: 24s   input: 132MB shuffle write: 120MB
` df_cache.rdd.groupBy(lambda x: int(x.time / 600e6) ).reduceByKey(lambda x: 1).collect()`

Comment: This takes only 9.47 seconds to finish. Seems to be right that it is way faster:
`df_cache.rdd.map(lambda x: (int(x.time / 600e6), (x.time, x.data)) ).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: 1).collect()`

Comment: Great, I'll mark the answer then and you can go forward and mark it as accepted. On a sidenote, you can try rewriting your job with a DataFrame, you might get even better performance.

Comment: Hey @andi, could you review the answer and accept it if it helped you ? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groupBy` is your bottleneck here : it needs to shuffle the data across all partitions, which is time consuming and takes a hefty space in memory, as you can see from your metrics.

The way to go here is to use the `reduceByKey` operation and chaining it as follow :
`df_cache.rdd.map(lambda x: (int(x.time/600e6), (x.time, x.data) ).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: 1).collect()`

The key takeaway here is that `groupBy` needs to shuffle all of your data across all partitions, whereas `reduceByKey` will first reduce on each of the partition and then across all partitions - reducing drastically the size of the global shuffle. Notice how I organized the input into a key to take advantage of the `reduceByKey` operation.

As I mentionned in the comments, you might also want to try your program by using Spark SQL's DataFrame abstraction, that can potentially give you an extra boost, thanks to its optimizer.